# List of Tuples to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tuples

I have a list of tuples which look like this

```
  [("color", "blue"), ("size","50"), ("length","60"),("color", "red"), ("size","40")]
```

And i would like to have a `csv` file like this (without that `Header`,`values` of course )

`Header`   1.  color | size | lenght

`values`   2.  blue  |  50  | 60

`values`   3.  red   |  40  | none

I tried this, but it does not work well

```py
with open('file.csv','w') as out:
    for title in final: # list name
        titles.append(title[0])
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(titles)
    for row in final:
        csv_out.writerows(row[1])
```

Comment: what do you mean by does not work well. what result are you expecting and what result did you get?

Comment: @abhilb Im expecting as I wrote above and I get a one line (row) with everything there without headers and values in rows

Comment: What if two colors appear one after another, or two lengths? Does it mean that they are related to two different items? Would the order of properties (color, size, length) always be the same for all items? As your data suggests that some info might be missing, this would be important to specify in your question.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille I requesting a list of tuples from function which is in loop and returns a one list at the time. This list contains a bunch of tuple in which I would like to use the first value as a header and second as a value in csv file. This tuples are in same order but they are not same, sometimes there is a tuple which was not in previous return. In this case I would like to add a new header with that tuple's first value and none or or just nothing to everything else where it doesn't appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict 
t = [("color", "blue"), ("size","50"), ("length","60"),("color", "red"), ("size","40")]
d = dict((y, x) for x, y in t)

res = defaultdict(list) 
for key, val in sorted(d.items()): 
    res[val].append(key)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res, orient='index').fillna(np.nan).T
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: great,happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer changing your approach a bit. 
You can simply put the `column_names` in a list like

```
column_names = ['color', 'size', 'length']
```

Then I would populate my data in a `list` of `lists` or preferable a `numpy array` like

```
data = np.array([('blue', 50, 60), ('red', 40, None)])
```

Then you can simple make a new dataframe via Pandas

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)
```

This thing will return you something like this

```
>>> my_dataframe
  color size length
0  blue   50     60
1   red   40   None
>>>
```

Then you can use pandas builtin `to_csv` method to save the dataframe locally as a CSV file.

```
my_datframe.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

And done.